# Can someone clarify how these parameters are being passed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't have much experience yet and I need clarification on functional components and arrow functions in JS. I have looked these up, but I am still a little confused in practice. For a project, my team is using an interactive mapping resource and I have this function my teammates put together, but they aren't great at explaining it. What I currently think: handleGeocoderViewportChange should be the function, viewport is the parameter, and it returns the result of another function handleViewportChange after passing parameters viewport and geocoderDefaultOverrides in spread notation for their properties. And the props like viewport are passed in when we create an object of this class in another component like

```
class Map extends Component {
  mapRef = React.createRef();
....
....
handleViewportChange = viewport => {
    this.props.setViewport(
      { ...this.props.viewport, ...viewport }
    );};
handleGeocoderViewportChange = viewport => {
    const geocoderDefaultOverrides = { transitionDuration: 1000 };
    return this.handleViewportChange({
      ...viewport,
      ...geocoderDefaultOverrides
    });
};
```

What I don't understand is that when we call the functions in the return, I don't see the parameters like viewport being passed to handleGeocoderViewportChange. I also dont understand how the props are being passed in automatically from when we create the object if for our class definition we didn't define it as: Maps(props) extends.... So how exactly are these parameters being passed?

```
return(){
    <MapGL
      ref={this.mapRef}
      {...this.props.viewport}
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      onViewportChange={this.handleViewportChange}
      mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      mapStyle='mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
    >
      <Geocoder
        mapRef={this.mapRef}
        onResult={this.props.handleSearch}
        onViewportChange={this.handleGeocoderViewportChange}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        position="top-left"
      />
```

Comment: I might be missing something but the 2nd piece of code you have pasted doesn't look like valid javascript

Comment: @Stuart it's JSX